# Two module verilog is not working

Tags: verilog, hdl, flip-flop, shift-register

```
module rff_try_1(q,inp,clk);
input clk,inp;
output q;
reg q;

DFF dff0(q,inp,clk);
endmodule

module DFF(q,inp,clk);
input inp,clk;
output q;
reg q;
always @ (posedge clk)begin 
if(clk)begin 
q=inp;
end
end

endmodule
```

here I'm using two modules but output is not coming
I'm trying to make two bit right shift register but 1st i have to make one single bit register but even this is not working

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in the code.

**1)** The line `if(clk)begin` and relevant `end` should be removed, `posedge clk` already describes trigger condition of the flip-flop.

**2)** A non-blocking assignment (`<=`) is required for the sequential logic.

The `always` block should be as follows:

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin 
    q <= inp;
end
```

**3)** Some simulators don't complain, but signal `q` should be `wire` in module `rff_try_1`.

```
wire q;
```

**Simulation**

I simulated the code (after the modifications) on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com) with the testbench below. Used *Icarus Verilog 0.9.7* as simulator.

```
module tb();

  reg clk = 1;
  always clk = #5 ~clk;

  reg  inp;
  wire q;

  rff_try_1 dut(q, inp, clk);

  initial begin
    inp = 0;
    #12;
    inp = 1;
    #27;
    inp = 0;
    #24;
    inp = 1;
  end

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
    #200;
    $finish;
  end

endmodule
```

The signal `q` is as expected as seen on the waveform.

[image]

Comment: thank you sir for your suggestion but i tried what u have said but my output still not showing anything !! i'm giving clock value to the clk and constant 1 to inp. you can check the code in your pc ! may be it will not show anything

Comment: @DipjyotiDas Could you add your testbench to the question, thus I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: we are using force clock to the clk and force constant to inp in xilinx and getting no output in q,does your pc showing any output??

Comment: @DipjyotiDas I simulated the code with my testbench, it gives the expected output. I will update the answer.

Comment: @DipjyotiDas You may use the simple testbench above instead of forcing the signals.